# VoIP between two different applications - React Native

Tags: react-native, sip, voip, voximplant, react-native-webrtc

I am researching how to implement VoIP between two different apps. In my case there are two applications. First one is for service users and the other one is for service providers. Final goal is to establish voice call between these two apps. They have different bundle IDs, but the same team ID. Implementation of both apps is in React Native. If anyone knows anything about this topic it will be of great help.

Thanks in advance

I was researching platforms like Twilio and Voximplant. I sent them emails, but there is no response for now. As I see, they offer services for VoIP calls between different users of the same applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to implement. You can integrate Voximplant sdk into your app to make calls:
https://voximplant.com/docs/gettingstarted/makeanapp/reactnative

Voximplant also have demo projects here:
https://github.com/voximplant/react-native-demo

If necessary, on the scenario side of the platform you will be able to send/receive api request from/to your server:
https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/appevents#httprequest
https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/net/httprequest